# How can I manipulate categorical data for logistic regression?

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to perform logistic regression on this dataset.
The first three columns are predictor variables. The fourth (value=No) and the fifth (value=Yes) columns are the response variables. For example, in the first ROW, there are 53 No's and 6 Yes's.
In the second row, there are 10 No's and 4 Yes's.

Below is the link for the data.

[data](https://data.princeton.edu/wws509/datasets/cuse.dat)

How can I convert this into a four-column data frame? Thank you.

What I want is something like this:

[image: results]

[image: data]

I tried using glm function directly:

```
K1=glm(formula = cbind(notUsing,using) ~ age + education + wantsMore, 
    data = as.data.frame(data_imported), family = "binomial")
```

The coefficients are :

```
> K1$coefficients
 (Intercept)     age25-29     age30-39     age40-49 educationlow wantsMoreyes 
   0.8082200   -0.3893816   -0.9086135   -1.1892389    0.3249947    0.8329548
```

Comment: How do you create `usage` column? What is the logic?

Comment: This seems like you have a binomial model on the form `glm(cbind(notUsing, Using) ~ age + education + wantsMore, data = [your df here], family = binomial)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on my comment here. Your data is already in the correct format for fitting a generalized linear model using R.

It is hidden quite well somewhere in the R-documentation, but I bet that if one read `help(formula)`, `help(glm)`, `help(lm)` or `help(family)` there's a note somewhere about this kind of behaviour.

In the case where you have two columns specifying `success` and `not success` the correct formula format is `cbind(success, not success) ~ explanatory variables`. For your specific case

```
glm(cbind(notUsing, Using) ~ age + education + wantsMore, data = [your df here], family = binomial)
```

can be used to fitting some kind of model.
This is (somewhat) equivalent to adding identical row for each `notUsing` and `Using`, eg for row 1, you'd have 53 rows where `usage = no` with `age = <25`, `education = low`, `wantsMore = yes`, and 6 rows where `usage = Yes`.

```
rows <- numeric(sum(df$notUsing + df$Using))
trials <- character(sum(df$notUsing + df$Using))
j <- 1
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  ind <- j:(j + df$notUsing[i] + df$using[i] - 1)
  first <- seq(df$notUsing[i])
  trials[ind[first]] <- 'No'
  trials[ind[-first]] <- 'Yes'
  rows[ind] <- i
  j <- j + df$notUsing[i] + df$using[i]
}
df_long <- cbind(df[rows, 1:3], data.frame(usage = trials))
#Identical coefficients, but different deviance and degrees of freedom
print(glm(usage ~ ., data = df_long, family = binomial))
print(glm(cbind(using, notUsing) ~ ., data = df, family = binomial))

#alternative binding methods "hiding" the loop.:
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
rbind(df %>% uncount(notUsing) %>% select(1:3) %>% add_column(usage = 'No'),
df %>% uncount(using) %>% select(1:3) %>% add_column(usage = 'Yes'))
```

Comment: The glm function returns very strange results. See additional information added in the post.

Comment: Using glm function directly returns more than four coefficients, which does not make sense. There should be just 4 coefficient including the intercept.

Comment: That is how most models works. Outside tree-based models, where some are implemented to handle catagorical splitting without transforming the data, other models have to transform catagorical columns into numeric columns. So each category gets their own column (except one, which is included in the 'intercept'). For more information i suggest looking up (factor) contrast treatment, creation of design matrices and other similar topics.